# setting up a new wifi in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, networking

Are there any drivers required to setup wifi connectivity using a new router in ubuntu 14.04 like in windows we need extra drivers each and everything ?

Comment: This is not a forum for chit chat. If you have a question for a particular device please provide sufficient information. http://askubuntu.com/q/14008/40581

Comment: Sorry for that,I have tp link's tp-wr740n router and want to setup connection through dsl cable.Pls tell me the procedure

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No. Ubuntu has almost the driver for every device on planet Earth or eve

Comment: That is a myth and not true. Drivers are also removed from time to time to lessen the maintenance burden.